# Select only columns with column names that match values from rows in other df

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, one that is a very large, wide dataset with hundreds of parameters and another with 3 columns that identify the parameters in the larger dataframe with specification limits and two columns for the lower and upper limits. What I want to do is to be able to reduce the wide dataframe to just the columns that are in the limits dataframe. I feel like this is incredibly basic but I cannot get it to work

See below for an example and output that I would like.

df

```
df <- data.frame("par.1" = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 5), "par.2" = c(10, 11, 12, 11, 15),"par.3" = c(8, 8, 12, 8, 9),"par.4" = c(8, 8, 12, 8, 9))
```

limits

```
limits <- data.frame("parameter" = c("par.2", "par.4"), "lsl" = c(8,5), "usl" = c(16,15))
```

Here is the output I am looking for

df.reduced

```
    par.2 par.4
1    10     8
2    11     8
3    12    12
4    11     8
5    15     9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subset `df` column names by values `%in%` the `parameter` column of `limits`

```
df[names(df) %in% limits$parameter]
  par.2 par.4
1    10     8
2    11     8
3    12    12
4    11     8
5    15     9
```

Comment: I knew it was so much easier than I was making it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `match`:

```
df[match(limits$parameter, names(df))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was way over complicating it.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `intersect`

```
df[intersect(names(df), as.character(limits$parameter))]
```